# Does the composer software have a command like python -m compileall ./

Tags: php, mediawiki, composer

I want to use composer for a mediawiki root folder with multiple directories
 that need composer to install their dependencies
 with a command like composer -m installall ./ 
For example , if the root folder was all written in python
 i could use the command python -m compileall ./

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about python, but looking at the description of compile all it is described as compiling bytecode, something which is not a core part of PHP and i can also not see how this is related to managing the root folder of mediawiki.

Looking separately at managing the root folder of mediawiki:

- mediawiki would have to be PSR1 or 4 compatible, which to my knowledge it is not
- somehow you would have to figure out how to manage the vendor folder in the same directory as the composer.phar file, i havent looked at if this is possible. Alternatively maybe you could point your webroot into the vendor folder.

It seems like a far fetched change for using composer, what is the problem you are trying to solve?